# How to represent 2 standard deviation values as one error

Tags: standard-deviation, error

I am working out a percentage survival between 2 conditions (e.g. in the presence/absence of antibiotic). For both mean values I have a standard deviation. How do represent the error in the % survival value that accounts for the SDs?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Why do you want to do it? Why can't you just present two numbers?

Comment: The error in which % survival value?